# How to parse nested RSS feeds?

Tags: android, xml-parsing, rss

I am using [enter link description here](http://www.hindustantimes.com/rss/books/rssfeed.xml)

I am able to fetch all required data from URL. But I want to fetch the `<item>...</item>` attribute as a List. I am able to fetch all attributes one by one. I want complete list of item attribute. 
Is their any other option for same?

Here is code for rss parsing.

```
public class HandleXML {

    public volatile boolean parsingComplete = true;
    private String title = "title";
    private String link = "link";
    private String description = "description";
    private String image = "image";
    private String imageTitle = "title";
    private String imageDescription = "description";
    private String imageLink = "link";
    private String guid = "guid";
    private String pubDate = "pubDate";
    private String media_content = "media:content";
    private String urlString = null;
    private XmlPullParserFactory xmlFactoryObject;
    private boolean isImage = false;

    public boolean isParsingComplete() {
        return parsingComplete;
    }

    public void setParsingComplete(boolean parsingComplete) {
        this.parsingComplete = parsingComplete;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getImageTitle() {
        return imageTitle;
    }

    public void setImageTitle(String imageTitle) {
        this.imageTitle = imageTitle;
    }

    public String getImageDescription() {
        return imageDescription;
    }

    public void setImageDescription(String imageDescription) {
        this.imageDescription = imageDescription;
    }

    public String getImageLink() {
        return imageLink;
    }

    public void setImageLink(String imageLink) {
        this.imageLink = imageLink;
    }

    public String getGuid() {
        return guid;
    }

    public void setGuid(String guid) {
        this.guid = guid;
    }

    public String getPubDate() {
        return pubDate;
    }

    public void setPubDate(String pubDate) {
        this.pubDate = pubDate;
    }

    public String getMedia_content() {
        return media_content;
    }

    public void setMedia_content(String media_content) {
        this.media_content = media_content;
    }

    public String getUrlString() {
        return urlString;
    }

    public void setUrlString(String urlString) {
        this.urlString = urlString;
    }

    public HandleXML(String url) {
        this.urlString = url;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void parseXMLAndStoreIt(XmlPullParser myParser) {
        int event;
        String text = null;

        try {
            event = myParser.getEventType();

            while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                String name = myParser.getName();

                switch (event) {
                    case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                        break;

                    case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                        text = myParser.getText();
                        break;

                    case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:

                        if (!isImage && name.equals("title")) {
                            title = text;
                            Log.e("Input text : ",text);
                        }
                        else if (!isImage && name.equals("link")) {
                            link = text;
                            Log.e("Input link : ",text);
                        }
                        else if (!isImage && name.equals("description")) {
                            description = text;
                            Log.e("Input description : ",text);
                        }
                        else if (name.equals("image")) {
                            image = text;
                            isImage = true;
                            Log.e("Input image : ",text);
                        }
                        else if (isImage && name.equals("title")) {
                            imageTitle = text;
                            Log.e("Input image title : ",text);
                        }
                        else if (isImage && name.equals("description")) {
                            imageDescription = text;
                            Log.e("Input image descr : ",text);
                        }
                        else if (isImage && name.equals("link")) {
                            imageLink = text;
                            Log.e("Input link : ",text);
                        }
                        else if (isImage && name.equals("guid")) {
                            guid = text;
                            Log.e("Input guid : ",text);
                        }
                        else if (isImage && name.equals("pubDate")) {
                            pubDate = text;
                            Log.e("Input pubdate : ",text);
                        }
                        else if (isImage && name.equals("media:content")) {
                            media_content = text;
//                            isImage = false;
                            Log.e("Input media:content : ",text);
                        }
                        break;
                }
                event = myParser.next();
            }
            parsingComplete = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void fetchXML() {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    URL url = new URL(urlString);
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                    conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
                    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    conn.setDoInput(true);
                    // Starts the query
                    conn.connect();
                    InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();

                    xmlFactoryObject = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                    XmlPullParser myparser = xmlFactoryObject.newPullParser();
                    myparser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
                    myparser.setInput(stream, null);
                    parseXMLAndStoreIt(myparser);
                    stream.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

How can get the item list? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should 
1) separate the Item class as model from HandleXML.
2) at the beginning of channel tag, init one item list. 
3) at the beginning of item tag, create a new item object. 
4) populate the Item object accordingly.
5) at the end of item tag, add the Item object to list.

You should pay attention to `isImage` variable. init should be true, once you create one item object, set to false.
The snippet is something as below:

```
public class HandleXML {

    public volatile boolean parsingComplete = true;
    private String image = "image";
    private String imageTitle = "title";
    private String imageDescription = "description";
    private String imageLink = "link";
    private String urlString = null;
    private XmlPullParserFactory xmlFactoryObject;
    private boolean isImage = true; // isImage init to be true

    private List<Item> itemList = null;

    // separate the Item class with HandleXML
    class Item {
        private String title = "title";
        private String link = "link";
        private String description = "description";
        private String guid = "guid";
        private String pubDate = "pubDate";
        private String media_content = "media:content";

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }

        public void setLink(String link) {
            this.link = link;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }

        public String getGuid() {
            return guid;
        }

        public void setGuid(String guid) {
            this.guid = guid;
        }

        public String getPubDate() {
            return pubDate;
        }

        public void setPubDate(String pubDate) {
            this.pubDate = pubDate;
        }

        public String getMedia_content() {
            return media_content;
        }

        public void setMedia_content(String media_content) {
            this.media_content = media_content;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public String getLink() {
            return link;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }
    }

    public boolean isParsingComplete() {
        return parsingComplete;
    }

    public void setParsingComplete(boolean parsingComplete) {
        this.parsingComplete = parsingComplete;
    }


    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getImageTitle() {
        return imageTitle;
    }

    public void setImageTitle(String imageTitle) {
        this.imageTitle = imageTitle;
    }

    public String getImageDescription() {
        return imageDescription;
    }

    public void setImageDescription(String imageDescription) {
        this.imageDescription = imageDescription;
    }

    public String getImageLink() {
        return imageLink;
    }

    public void setImageLink(String imageLink) {
        this.imageLink = imageLink;
    }

    public String getUrlString() {
        return urlString;
    }

    public void setUrlString(String urlString) {
        this.urlString = urlString;
    }

    public HandleXML(String url) {
        this.urlString = url;
    }


    public void parseXMLAndStoreIt(XmlPullParser myParser) {
        int event;
        String text = null;
        Item newItem = null;

        try {
            event = myParser.getEventType();

            while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                String name = myParser.getName();

                switch (event) {
                    case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("channel")) {
                            // init the list for item.
                            itemList = new ArrayList<Item>();
                        }
                        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                            // create a new item object.
                            newItem = new Item();
                            isImage = false; // isImage to false
                        }
                        break;

                    case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                        text = myParser.getText();
                        break;

                    case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:

                        if (!isImage && name.equals("title")) {
                            newItem.setTitle(text);
                            Log.e("Input text : ",text);
                        }
                        else if (!isImage && name.equals("link")) {
                            newItem.setLink(text);
                            Log.e("Input link : ",text);
                        }
                        else if (!isImage && name.equals("description")) {
                            newItem.setDescription(text);
                            Log.e("Input description : ",text);
                        }
                        else if (name.equals("image")) {
                            image = text;
                            isImage = true;
                            Log.e("Input image : ",text);
                        }
                        else if (isImage && name.equals("title")) {
                            imageTitle = text;
                            Log.e("Input image title : ",text);
                        }
                        else if (isImage && name.equals("description")) {
                            imageDescription = text;
                            Log.e("Input image descr : ",text);
                        }
                        else if (isImage && name.equals("link")) {
                            imageLink = text;
                            Log.e("Input link : ",text);
                        }
                        else if (!isImage && name.equals("guid")) {
                            newItem.setGuid(text);
                            Log.e("Input guid : ",text);
                        }
                        else if (!isImage && name.equals("pubDate")) {
                            newItem.setPubDate(text);
                            Log.e("Input pubdate : ",text);
                        }
                        else if (!isImage && name.equals("media:content")) {
                            newItem.setMedia_content(text);
//                            isImage = false;
                            Log.e("Input media:content : ",text);
                        }
                        else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                            // add the item to list in the end of item tag
                            itemList.add(newItem);
                            Log.e("itemList", "Add one");
                        }
                        break;
                }
                event = myParser.next();
            }
            parsingComplete = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void fetchXML() {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    URL url = new URL(urlString);
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                    conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
                    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    conn.setDoInput(true);
                    // Starts the query
                    conn.connect();
                    InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();

                    xmlFactoryObject = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                    XmlPullParser myparser = xmlFactoryObject.newPullParser();
                    myparser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
                    myparser.setInput(stream, "UTF_8");
                    parseXMLAndStoreIt(myparser);
                    stream.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: It shows ItemList size always 0.  Item never get added in List.

Comment: Please check the snippet again. I test the item will be added to the list.